# How to blacklist directory loading in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, dependencies, activeadmin

I want to disable ActiveAdmin when running the tests.

So I add `require: false` to the Gemfile and checking `if defined?(ActiveAdmin)` in routes and initializer.

But Rails still loads the models form `app/admin` thus I am getting error similar to `/app/admin/admin_user.rb:1:in`': uninitialized constant ActiveAdmin (NameError)`

What is the best way to "blacklist" the `app/admin` directory from being loaded?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
# config/environments/test.rb

path_rejector = lambda { |s| s.include?("app/admin") }

# Remove the path from being loaded when Rails starts:
config.eager_load_paths = config.eager_load_paths.reject(&path_rejector)

# Remove the path from being lazily loaded
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths.reject!(&path_rejector)
```

Answer (score 0):

In config/application.rb add:

```
config.paths.delete("app/admin")
new_eager_load_paths = config.eager_load_paths.dup
new_eager_load_paths.delete("/mnt/hgfs/project/app/admin")
config.eager_load_paths = new_eager_load_paths
```

You have to replace "/mnt/hgfs/project/eventmust/app/admin" by your path, it's not very clean but it's work.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. The `config.paths` doesn't have the `app/admin` path at all. Removing it from `new_eager_load_paths` doesn't load the file eagerly, but still tries to do it later on by some Rails magic (for example loading `DashboarsController` - loads the `admin/dashboard.rb` which shouldn't happen). Thoughts?

Comment: In rails 3.2.8, i test with just a class in a file in app/admin and it's work :(. Inspect your config.paths and config.eager_load_paths, and maybe try to add the 4lines at the end of file config/application.rb (just before the 2 "end").

Comment: On Rails `3.2.8` too. Already inspected the paths and removed all references to the `admin` path. Also doing it at the end of the `environments/test.rb` (which is loaded after `config/application.rb` and confirmed that it actually is loaded).